# How to set intellij's editor configuration of spaces within imports for .vue files

Tags: intellij-idea, editorconfig

Is there any Intellij's .editorconfig options for .vue files(starting with ij_vue_xxx) that behave like below?
I can't find any options that apply to .vue files. If not, please let me know if there is another way.

```
# for typescript, not vue.

[*.{ts, vue}]
ij_typescript_spaces_within_imports
ij_typescript_force_quote_style = true
ij_typescript_use_double_quotes = false

# I want it to behave like ij_vue_spaces_within_imports
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bug for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43126

Feel free to watch it in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.